# alert occurs more that one time for each button click in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, modal-dialog

I have created a section in my php page with jquery and ajax, the response would create a button related to the index of the class of an element to open a modal for each. it is fine so far, but the problem is that when I click on a any input inside that modal it alerts(sends) the message based on the amount of clicks that happened on the main button.
for example the jquery created a section with 4 button, each button opens a different or similar modal, when any button that is inside of the modal is clicked (for the first time) everything works fine, when the modal is closed and reopened or other modal opened , by clicking on a button inside the opened modal the alert happens twice, if modal got closed and other one opened on click the inside button alert happens three times and so one. here is the code:

````
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var openbutton = $('.palette');

                $.each(openbutton, function() {

                    $(this).on('click', function() {
                        var devicename = $(this).attr('name');
                        var serial = $(this).attr('value');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "modal.php",
                            data: {
                                devicename: devicename,
                                serial: serial
                            },
                            success: function(data1) {
                                $('#palettesection').html(data1);
                                alert(devicename + "---" + serial);
                            },
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>```   

and this is the modal code:

    ```<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var intensity = $('.button');
                    var intens = [];
                    var t;
                    var serial = $('.section').attr('value');
                   
                    $(document).on('click', '.intensity', function() {
                        
                        $.each(intensity, function(i) {
                            t = $(this).val();
                            intens.splice(i, intensity.length, t);
                        });
                     
                        alert('value: ' + intens);
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "dev_values.php",
                            data: {
                                serial: serial,
                                intens: intens
                            },
        
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('#value2').html(data);
                              
        
                            }
        
                        });
        
                    });
                });
            </script>```

------------------------------------------------------------
it would be really appreciated if some could help me in this issue.
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

````
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var openbutton = $('.palette');

            $.each(openbutton, function() {

                $(this).on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventdefault();
                    var devicename = $(this).attr('name');
                    var serial = $(this).attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "modal.php",
                        data: {
                            devicename: devicename,
                            serial: serial
                        },
                        success: function(data1) {
                            $('#palettesection').html(data1);
                            alert(devicename + "---" + serial);
                        },
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    </script>```
````

and this is the modal code:

````
```<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var intensity = $('.button');
                var intens = [];
                var t;
                var serial = $('.section').attr('value');
               
                $(document).on('click', '.intensity', function(e) {
                    e.preventdefault();
                    $.each(intensity, function(i) {
                        t = $(this).val();
                        intens.splice(i, intensity.length, t);
                    });
                 
                    alert('value: ' + intens);
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "dev_values.php",
                        data: {
                            serial: serial,
                            intens: intens
                        },
    
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#value2').html(data);
                          
    
                        }
    
                    });
    
                });
            });
        </script>```
````

Comment: Many thanks but it did not work. I found another solution which is ".unbind()" command. now it works .